# Singularities in convex functions of more than one variable

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

I've heard that a convex function of a single variable is continuous in the interior of its domain, and is differentiable everywhere with the possible exception of a countable number of points. (I haven't seen a proof of this but I believe it.)

I am interested in how this generalises to convex functions of more than one variable. Specifically, from geometric intuition it seems that a convex function of two variables can fail to be differentiable along lines as well as points; it's possible for three or more of these lines to meet at a point, or for a line to terminate.

There can also be regions of the domain in which one or more of the partial derivatives vanish; I'm not sure but I think these have to be convex sets. I suspect much more interesting things can happen with three or more variables, but it's a little hard to visualise.

In general one could construct a kind of map or "phase diagram" of the function's domain, indicating the areas in which one or more of the partial derivatives diverges or vanishes. The convexity condition evidently puts strong constraints on what features this diagram can have. I would like to know whether a general theory has been worked out for this, for general convex functions of $n$ variables.

The motivation for the question comes from phase changes in physics. I would like to know to what extent the existence of phenomena such as universality classes emerges simply from the fact that the entropy (and its Legendre dual, the partition function) is a convex function.

Is there a theory on the types of singularity that can occur in convex functions of multiple variables? If so what is it called, and where can I read more about it?

Comment: For future reference, the following paper seems closely related to my question and may provide a partial answer. However, I'm barely able to follow any of its terminology - perhaps future-me will have better luck. http://www.dm.unipi.it/cluster-pages/alberti/files/ricerca/1989-91/alambcan-rdc.pdf

Comment: One reference to be aware of is Convex Analysis by Rockafellar.